# Why $2\mathbb{Z} $ is not integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that $\mathbb{Z}$  is  an integral domain .if $ca = cb$, where $a, b, c \in Z$ and $c \neq 0$...

Now  my Question  is that  Why $2\mathbb{Z} $ is not integral domain ?

pliz help me,,,,

thanks u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In commutative ring theory, we generally require that a ring contains a multiplicative identity element. Such an element is not contained in $2\Bbb Z$, so we wouldn't consider it a ring, and therefore not an integral domain.

If your ring theory does not require a multiplicative identity, then $2\Bbb Z$ is a ring. In that case, it would also be an integral domain.

Comment: Hmm I'm confused... why are there so many definitions for rings/integral domains? In Dummit & Foote where I learned, $2\mathbb{Z}$ would be a ring and not an integral domain, because it doesn't have an identity. If someone is talking about rings, how can I know which definition they're using?

Comment: @Ovi If they don't tell you, you can't know which definition they're using. That's just the way it is, sorry. Some times you may be able to glean from context, but that's it. As for why there are so many definitions, that's just what happens when a field is developed independently by many mathematicians, none of whom know what will actually turn out to be important in the end.

Comment: Oh I thought there may be a standard definition which the majority of people use, because everything I've read on stackexcahgen is consistent with the definitions I got from Dummit & Foote

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you want to have an identity - if you insist on having then it isn't, otherwise it is.

Here's a useful link: https://www.quora.com/Is-2Z-an-integral-domain